# Issue in accessing Azure Keyvault - DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm accessing values stored in an Azure Keyvault. Using Visual Studio for my development I'm able to get the data from Keyvault without any issues. However, when the code is deployment to different environments like Test or Stage, I'm getting an error.

The credentials that I'm using to access the Keyvault is stored in the Environment Variables of the project.

*Visual Studio > Project > Right-click on Properties > Debug > Environment variables*.

The environment variables contain:

- Azure_Client_Id
- Azure_Tenant_Id
- Azure_Client_Secret

The code to access the Keyvault is below and this works fine when used through Visual Studio.

```
var KeyVaultData = new Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(@"https://{VaultName}.vault.azure.net/"), credential: new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential());
```

However when this is deployed to other environments, I'm getting the error below:

> ***Exception occured** - Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
> EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
> SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.*

I don't have access to Azure, but was informed that everything has been setup correctly.

Any help on resolving this is very much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
New code based on the solution given:

```
const string tenantId = "-----"; 
const string clientId = "-----";
const string clientSecret = "-----";  
var keyvaultCredentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret); 
var KeyVaultData= new SecretClient(new Uri(@"https://{VaultName}.vault.azure.net/"), keyvaultCredentials);
```

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: @JoyWang Thanks for your response. Sorry, I wasn't able to check it, let me modify my code and respond to you.

Comment: Hi, do you get it now?

Comment: Thank you for following up. Based on your response, now I'm able to get the values from the Key Vault in Visual Studio (New code is just below my question). However I haven't moved the code to different environments since I've hard-coded the credentials. Do I save these credentials in secrets.json or appsettings? And if saved in either of them, what corresponding changes should I request to be done in Azure?

Comment: No, you need to pass the credentials directly to the constructor, because this way is applied to all the environments, for different environments, there are better ways.

Comment: I've deployed the code to the Test environment and facing a different error this time. When I'm within my official network and running the code from Visual Studio it is working fine. However, after it was deployed got the error:  

Exception occured Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.Status: 403 (Forbidden)

Content:
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.{"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"}}}

Comment: It caused by the firewall of your keyvault, navigate to the Networking of your keyvault in the portal, you need to allow all access or add your ip address to the firewall.

Comment: Adding the IP addresses will be a problem, since the application might be hosted on the internet. Is there any other way to get the values from the Keyvault?

Answer (score 3):

The `DefaultAzureCredential` will use environment variables automatically in local, so if you have set the environment variables, of course, it will work. If the environment variables are not available, it will try `ManagedIdentityCredential`,
`SharedTokenCacheCredential`,
`InteractiveBrowserCredential`, when you deploy your code to the environments you mentioned, they are all not available, so you will get the error.

In this case, if you want to deploy your code to different environments, you need to use [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet), pass the parameters directly to [`ClientSecretCredential(String, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Identity_ClientSecretCredential__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_), then the code will work anywhere.

```
public ClientSecretCredential (string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I deployed my app using DefaultAzureCredential:

```
Azure.Identity DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot 
 EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
```

I found the answer here:  [How to use DefaultAzureCredential in both local and hosted Environment (Azure and On-Premise) to access Azure Key Vault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616431/how-to-use-defaultazurecredential-in-both-local-and-hosted-environment-azure-an)

The solution was to assign the Managed Id to my Web App under Identity / User Assigned.