# Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException GetCertificate from AzureKeyVault using azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, azure-keyvault

I have an app which uses certificates ( Uploaded the cert) in Azure Azure KeyVault.

I am trying to use asp.net application 4.7 to connect to key vault and retrieve the application Certificate and the Secret associate with it

Previously I used Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault and KeyVaultClient in combination with GetCertificateAsync and GetSecretAsync to pull the certificate and its secret.

However I recognized that **Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault is deprecated** so i researched and I found That I should use **Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates**  instead.

I wrote the below code
**New Way:**

using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;
public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromVault(string keyVaultName, string certificateName)
{

```
       var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/";


        var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy keyVaultCertificateWithPolicy = client.GetCertificate(certificateName);
        return new X509Certificate2(keyVaultCertificateWithPolicy.Cer);
    }
```

However I get error on calling client.GetCertificate(certificateName); in above code which is my new way
Here is the error

Multiple exceptions were encountered while attempting to authenticate. ---> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: E
nvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
[https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot\r\n](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot%5Cr%5Cn)   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)\r\n   at
Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential.d__12.MoveNext()\r\n

I have **KeyVaultCertificateOfficer** role and I can retrieve the certificates using my old way on the local machine so I am sure I do not have access issue.

I looked at developer guide it says that I need to create
environment variables for AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, and AZURE_TENANT_ID
Is that the solution? I do not understand why? Do I need to do this on all my different environment like UAT and PROD and create these variables. I kind of dont like that so i think i missing something here.

If I absolutely need to create env variables also not sure what to use as
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET as I use Certificate not secret for my App. I saw AZURE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PATH but that is the path to pfx in local machine right which we do not want that.

Maybe my understanding is totally wrong I am not sure. So any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think when you're using DefaultAzureCredential, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616431/how-to-use-defaultazurecredential-in-both-local-and-hosted-environment-azure-an.  There's a good Microsoft explanation for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Above link suggest to create Manage identity. How ever I have an on premise application , The app pool identity account ( It is 
 a service account in ad which is synced to azure Ad ) currently has access to key vault. I want  to use my existing service account that has already access to key vault instead of creating managed identity which is brand new entry in Ad is that possible? And if it is I wonder how?

Comment: I can use the following to get the secrets from the vault with out any env variable

Comment: public static string GetSecretFromVault(string keyVaultName, string secretName,string tenantId, string clientId)
{
 var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/";
 //used ClientSecretCredential instead of DefaultAzureCredential()
 var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), 
          new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId,
                clientId: clientId,
                clientSecret:"123"));
 var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
 return secret.Value.Value;
}

Comment: How ever i am not sure how to do this using certificate instead of application Secret. I veleive if i want to use ClientCertificateCredential i need to have pfx on local machine

Comment: With Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault I couldhave passed the certificate name and get the identifier and from there get the secret. I need to do the same with Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates any idea on that?

Comment: Actually 7- identity options, DefaultAzureCredential combines some classes, that are used to retrieve AAD identity. It tries to initialize them one by one (in this order). The first successfully initialized credential is used:
EnvironmentCredential,ManagedIdentityCredential,SharedTokenCacheCredential,VisuaStudioCredential,VisualStudioCodeCredential,AzureCliCredential,InteractiveBrowserCredential.  https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/defaultazurecredential-from-azure-sdk/   -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth#default-azure-credential

Comment: var client = new CertificateClient(vaultUri: new Uri(vaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());   -  in this example 2nd parameter shouldn't be the default Azure Credential to prevent from using 7-Identity options in the previous comment, but service account credential, possibly  new DefaultAzureCredential(azureCredentialOptions) from rahulpanth.com in comment above.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I tried the below code using the link you mentioned no luck. In the docs it says DefaultAzureCredential is used for application that in cloud. Maybe that is why var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/";
var azureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
 azureCredentialOptions.SharedTokenCacheUsername = "ADD User Account";
var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(azureCredentialOptions));
var cert = client.GetCertificate("Cert-D-CC-KV-test");

Comment: I still get the error still get error DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

*Create a key Vault and certificate in azure*

[image]

[image]

*And we have chosen the same `.Net4.7 Framework`*

[image]

*Used the NuGet package* "***Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates***

[image]

The below namspaces are used in the application

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
```

*Below is the code used for fetching the certificates from azure*

```
 string certificateName = "TestCertificate";
 var KeyVaultUri = @"https://KeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/";
 var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(KeyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
 KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy keyVaultCertificateWithPolicy = client.GetCertificate(certificateName);
 var res= new X509Certificate2(keyVaultCertificateWithPolicy.Cer);
```

*Certificate details are fetched in below screens*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! sorry I did not have time during holidays to look into this. I will test it and respond back