# Azure DefaultAzureCredential is trying to get the oauth token from 169.254.169.254 in a development environment

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I was working with Azure SDK in .NET 7 and I run into an authentication issue when following the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection) to use Azure clients with dependency injection in a .NET project when using `DefaultAzureCredential` and Azure CLI login.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddAzureClients(builder => {
            builder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            builder.AddClient<ArmClient, ArmClientOptions>((options, creds) => new ArmClient(creds));
        });
    })
    .Build();

var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var sub = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Sub ID from direct DefaultAzureCredential(): " + sub.Id);

armClient = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ArmClient>();
sub = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Sub ID from DI: " + sub.Id);
```

I tested this code on different machines and every machine got the first client connection correctly and then failed to get the one from dependency injection with the following error:

```
info: Azure.Core[1]
      Request [03e2d65f-5d81-4842-a5f5-df1a6fb1422b] GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=REDACTED
      Metadata:REDACTED
      x-ms-client-request-id:03e2d65f-5d81-4842-a5f5-df1a6fb1422b
      x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
      User-Agent:azsdk-net-Identity/1.8.2 (.NET 7.0.5; Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621)
      client assembly: Azure.Identity
info: Azure.Core[18]
      Request [03e2d65f-5d81-4842-a5f5-df1a6fb1422b] exception Azure.RequestFailedException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.254:80)
```

So, for some reason, in a local environment and only when using dependency injection, `DefaultAzureCredential` is thinking that my machine is an Azure resource and try to connect to the internal metadata service to get the oauth token.
If I replace `DefaultAzureCredential` with `AzureCliCredential` everything works without issues.

I've shared an MRE here: https://github.com/fuji97/default-azure-credential-error

Comment: That's the endpoint of a managed identity. `DefaultAzureCredential` will attempt multiple methods of obtaining a key first trying the ones for a deployed application, which includes the managed identity. If that doesn't work it continues and should attempt Azure CLI if all other methods before it fail.

Comment: @NotFound Yes, it is attempting to log in using managed identity, but for some reason, it crashes because It's trying to get an OAuth token from an internal Azure metadata server, and that causes the `DefaultAzureCredential` to fail before even testing the Azure CLI provider

Comment: I seem to be running into the same issue. I have set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT correctly to Development in my launchsettings.json. But when using DefaultCredential I get the above error. Switching to AzureCLICredential like SiddheshDesai suggests fixes it, but only for my local machine of course. Is this a bug? Has anyone made a bug report for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your code in my console application and received the same error:-

[image]

[image]

Even after the above error as I logged into my Azure Account, **I received the desired output like below:-**

[image]

[image]

> According to the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456957/issue-in-accessing-azure-keyvault-defaultazurecredential-failed-to-retrieve-a) by Joy Wang The DefaultAzureCredentials will use Environment Variables
> if you have set them in your visual studio and if the Environment Variables are not available it will perform -
> `ManagedIdentityCredential`,`SharedTokenCacheCredential` `InteractiveBrowserCredential` As you're trying to get some custom meta data the DefaultAzureCredential is using ManagedIdentityCredential method in your code.

You can set the Environment Variable like below in your VS Studio:-

[image]

**When I changed the method to AzureCLICredentials, I got the desired output:-**

[image]

Comment: Yes, environment variables are working, but my idea was to use the CLI credential. I'm sure it works because if I switch to `AzureCliCredential` then it works. The issue seems to be that `DefaultAzureCredential` is trying to login with a managed identity when it should be skipped because I'm a development environment. My goal is to find why it isn't skipping the managed identity provider and crashing on it

Comment: @michasaucer No. not really. I just disabled `ManagedIdentityCredential` when I'm not in production